# How to add event to the body of a dynamically created iframe in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried:

```
$(document).on("event", window.iframe_name.doument.getElementsByTagName["body"][0], function(){
    //code
});
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Is the page on the same domain as your web page?

Comment: Could you post the iframe's markup?

Comment: <iframe id="upload_target" src="#" name="upload_target"></iframe>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to wait for the iFrame to load.

```
$(function(){
    $('#iFrame').load(function(){
        //then set up some access points
         var frame = document.getElementById('iFrame'); // referance to the iframe
         var frameWindow = frame.contentWindow; // referance the iframes window
         var contents = $(this).contents(); // contents of the iframe

         frameWindow.$('body').on(//your code here)

    })
})
```